# how to use CSS to set markdown list bullets style by markdown list symbol used

Tags: css, list, markdown

I know I can use CSS to set different markdown unordered list bullet styles,
but that works for each markdown list symbol I use.

#### file Markdown:

```
- elem1
  + elem2
+ elem3
  - elem4
  - elem5
```

#### file CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

#### HTML result:

All elements are with a square:
https://pasteboard.co/IxPSlcj.png

---

Is there some way to set a bullet style of SOME elements not by indentation level but by using a specific symbol? 
To be more specific, what CSS code and/or markdown processor and/or markdown enhancement allows me to write the same markdown as above but gives me an HTML like this:

https://pasteboard.co/IxQ28hH.png

---

#### EDIT

=> After some nice discussions here, I concluded it's just not possible

Comment: No....this is not possible,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what Markdown processor that you are using. Basic Markdown does not have the ability to provide context in the markup that could inform CSS styles. Some variations of Markdown might support an enhancement that could lead to a usable solution.

Without changing processors, your best bet would be to post-process the HTML to include enough styling information to achieve what you want. It could be as simple as adding a class to a specific page's `<body>` tag. Then you could add a style like:

```css
body.special ul > li:first-child > ul > li {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not searching for a post-process HTML solution. I could use any markdown processor and/or any markdown enhancement but I found none that could lead to a usable solution (Thanks I'll update the question to add that). For the moment I just think Paulie_D is right, it's not possible using just CSS and Markdown. 
I'm setting this as the best answer because it's the most complete one.

Comment: If you are open to other Markdown processors, perhaps you are open to an alternative markup format: AsciiDoc? Using Asciidoctor, you can specify roles, which become CSS class names, almost anywhere you like. AsciiDoc markup would solve your problem fairly easily.

Comment: I looked at the Asciidoc and Asciidoctor tool, but how do I create a role that solves my question? It seems to me list "roles" applies to all asciidoc list symbol I use, same behaviour as markdown. Am I missing something?

Comment: Asciidoctor is, in this particular situation, also limited, in that it cannot apply a role directly to a listitem. You can apply a role to a list, and use CSS to style specific listitems. Alternatively, a listitem can embed an open block (that has a role) that contains another list. As an author, the markup is not ideal/intuitive, but it is possible. With Markdown, it's just not possible.